# CGI file is overloading the server

Tags: perl, apache, cgi, fastcgi

I use movable type 5 for my CMS and I generate my pages dynamically.
the particular file that is causing the overload while generating the page is perl-dynamic.cgi

Is there any way to contain the load for this file only?

I know you can set in httpd.conf

```
RLimitCPU 20
RLimitNPROC 10
```

but this will apply to all the files and I don't want that.  Sorry I am not server expert.  If there is any other way to not overload the server with CGI files I would like to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit directives to specific files using `<Files>` (as per [the Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#files)).

Comment: can this be done with specific file name? or by extension only?

Comment: You appear to have skipped to the example of how to match files using a regular expression. Don't rush ahead: "The filename argument should include a filename…"

Comment: So you suggest something like this? <Files ~ "\perl-dynamic.cgi$">
RLimitNPROC 5 
RLimitCPU 30
</Files>

Comment: @Maca: Just `<Files perl-dynamic.cgi>` should do it.  Or `<Files ~ ^perl-dynamic\.cgi$>` or `<FilesMatch ^perl-dynamic\.cgi$>` if you _insist_ on using a regexp.

Comment: Thanks I am going to test this!